# Cycle inside {PROJECT} building could produce unreliable results. Cycle details

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15

I have just updated to XCODE 15 and Macos SONOMA. I'm receiving this issue regarding cycles:

```
Cycle inside MyApp; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'MyApp': ExtractAppIntentsMetadata
○ Target 'MyApp': CodeSign /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework
○ Target 'MyApp' has copy command from '/Users/me/Desktop/Checkouts/MyApp/theApp/MyApp/ios/3rdPartyFramework.framework' to '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework'
○ Target 'MyApp' has copy command from '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CallExtension.appex' to '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/PlugIns/CallExtension.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'MyApp': script phase “Add Git/CI Build Info”
○ Target 'MyApp' has process command with output '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'MyApp' has copy command from '/Users/me/Desktop/Checkouts/MyApp/theApp/MyApp/ios/3rdPartyFramework.framework' to '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework'


Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectA.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ExtractedAppShortcutsMetadata.stringsdata ->

command: P0:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:ExtractAppIntentsMetadata ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--package-copy-files-phase> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--package-copy-files-phase ->

node: <target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase11-copy-files> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6--fused-phase11-copy-files ->

node: <CodeSign /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework> ->

command: P0:target-MyApp-2a7e5ca2b3fd2ca0faca1487721e3ae07ceb6b36bcfc2fb90f69ac96de4975d6-:Debug:CodeSign /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework ->

node: <Copy /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectA-frqscjhianktlvbxgbzostesljpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/3rdPartyFramework.framework> ->

CYCLE POINT ->
```

Which I have found some solutions, but can't seem to find how to add them:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731825

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731287

This is one of the solutions, but where can I find this files:

```
1. Goto Build Phase tab.
2. Drag /Embed App Extension' and place it below 'Run script'.
```

**UPDATE:**
After running the following resolutions below, it made the app install and tried to launch, but the launch fails with `After running now, i get Terminated due to signal 6`

Comment: Hi, did you figure out any solution in the end? I'm having both problems - "cycle inside", then after re-arranging build phases - terminated when launching app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my case, seems to resolve if you move up "Embed Foundation Extensions" just right bellow "Copy Bundle Resources" in the Build Phases.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: My App has `Embed App Extension` instead of `Foundation`, it installed but did not seem to launch.

Comment: After running now, i get `Terminated due to signal 6`

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF, see screenshot bellow, there is Embed App Extension. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, similar to ziqq's answer,  I moved up "Embed App Extensions" just right bellow "Copy Bundle Resources" in the Build Phases.

[image]

Comment: My App has `Embed App Extension` instead of `Foundation`, it installed but did not seem to launch.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers to this question are correct. However, after researching, it is recommended that the embedded related script should be placed below "Copy Bundle Resources" in the Build Phases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answers above that involve changing the order of Build Phases fixed building my app. However, my app would crash on launch on iOS versions below 17.0.
It turned out there was a bug in the connectivity_plus package that has since been fixed. I tracked the bug by building to an iOS 16.4 emulator from XCode. An exception breakpoint would repeatedly trigger in a file from that package.
https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus/changelog#500